# Azure LogicApp Designer goes blank in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a LogicApp in Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.28 using the Azure Logic App Tools 2.24.2 extension. It has always been working fine. Used to work on several logic apps during the past 2 years. However, since a few days I keep getting this absurd behaviour where the whole panel just turns gray while I am working. In specific, it happens as soon as I try to add a new action or to open a condition block, as you will be able to see from the screenshots below. I have been looking for a solution here and there, but I could not find the same issue anywhere and I don't know how to solve this in order to keep on working.
Keep in mind that working directly on the Azure portal is not a possible option. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8kbK.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCJLP.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaNHb.png)

Already tried:

- Updated VS to latest version
- Made sure the Logic App Tools extension is updated
- Clone the repository from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced in My environment and created a logic app project name **"test2"**. It worked fine for me.

I did not face any problem like "blank screen".

I even tried using **"condition"** as you mentioned.You were facing blank screen issue during **"condition"** creation.

Please check images as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you still face any issues, I suggest you to reach out for Azure support for further assistance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for making this attempt. 
Unfortunately it still does not work on my side. I even tried to open my project on another machine and the misbehaviour presented itself again shortly. Note that it happens only with one specific logic app and not with others. I assume it might be related to the complexity of the logic app, which does not justify this error though, since there should not be a limitation on how big the logic app may be.

Comment: Please create the specific logic app in Azure Portal.

Comment: Please don't post an answer that basically says "this problem is not reproducible". Instead, flag or vote to close the question as not reproducible.